# Integration of multiple of characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function and $ a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $g(x)=1,\text{ if }x=a \text{ and }
 g(x)=0,\text{ if } x \neq a$.
Then what is the value of $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) dx$.

Could someone please help me evaluating the integration? I guess the answer is $f(a)$ .

Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $fg = 0$ a.e.

Answer (score 1):

A point is negligible for the Lebesgue measure so $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx=0.$$

Comment: Yes, can the limit be equal to f(a) by a suitable change in the question?

Comment: The limit of what ?

Comment: The same in the question. Whether that can be f(a) by a slight change in the question

Comment: I don't see an explicit limit in your question